Scale a set of vectors along the sum of them while preserving the magnitude of each vector
Given a set of $n$ vectors $\vec{a}_i$, each with the same magnitude $||{\vec{a}_i}|| = c$, and a target vector $\vec{t}$.
Let's define
\begin{equation}
\vec{s} = \sum_{i=0}^{n}\vec{a}_i
\end{equation}
It is additionally known that $\vec{s}=k \vec{t}$. How do the components of $\vec{a}_i$ have to be adjusted to get $\vec{s}=\vec{t}$, while preserving $||{\vec{a}_i}|| = c$?

Example:

In this particular example in 2D, with only $n=1$, we have two solutions, namely $\vec{a}_1 = [\frac{1}{4}(2+\sqrt{13}), \frac{1}{4}(2-\sqrt{13})]$ and $\vec{a}_1 = [\frac{1}{4}(2-\sqrt{13}), \frac{1}{4}(2+\sqrt{13})]$. If this were 3D, we would already have infinite solutions, since the two vectors could rotate around $\vec{t}$. I am interested in any of them, I just need one.

My current idea/approach:
So far, I have realised that there are cases of $\vec{a}_i$ where no such solution exists (when $\sum ||\vec{a}_i|| < ||\vec{t}||$ or $a_i$ does not contain a basis), and on the other hand cases where infinite solutions exist. I am interested in the later case, though one of the solutions is sufficient.
Intuitively, I would think of

rotating my $\vec{a}_i$ into a coordinate system where $\vec{t}$ is an axis,
where I therefore only have an imposed scaling in one dimension, that axis, per $i$ and
can e.g. scale uniformly in all other dimensions such that the norm is preserved, and finally
rotate back into the original carthesian coordinate system.

So far, I was not able to express this mathematically and would be thankful for any pointers on (a) whether this proposed method works, and (b) how this coordinate transformation would need to be done (I confuse myself over and over when trying to transform coordinates between coordinate systems).

I think you've not described your problem well. If you scale $||\vec a_i||$ by $\alpha$ then you get $||\alpha\vec a_i|| = \alpha||\vec a_i||$. There is fundamentally no way to preserve the norm when scaling, that is sort of the whole point of scaling. But I feel like this is not what you meant by "scaling $\vec a_i$".

Thanks for your comment, @NicholasTodoroff, you are right, "scaling" in that sense is not the correct word. Maybe "modify the components of $\vec{a}_i$" better explains what I mean?

Maybe you could clarify with an example of a case where you get no solutions and where you get infinite solutions, e.g. for $n=1$. The way that I'm understanding this is that (when $n=1$) you're looking for $b_0, b_1$ such that $||b_0||=||b_1||=c$ and $b_0+b_1 = t$, where $t = \frac{1}{k}(a_0+a_1)$. Is that the correct interpretation?

thank you too, @RandyMarsh for your comment. I have expanded my question with an illustration of an example, $n=1$, as you say. Yes, I think your understanding is correct.
